# Stack implementation using array C++

Tags: c++, class, stack

I am trying to implement some of the methods of the class "stack". For the push() method I am trying to duplicate the capacity of the array if the top of the stack equals the capacity. The top is the item of the next slot. I was doing this by creating a new array with double the capacity of the original array and then copying the content over. All the other methods I implemented (empty(), pop(), top()) seem to be working fine but the push function prints random values for the first 4 items of the stack for some reason if the stack has more than 10 elements (The capacity had to be increased). Why is this problem happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
    public:
        stack();
        bool empty();
        void pop();
        void push(int x);
        int &topElem();
    
    private:
        int *buffer;
        int top;                          // Top element of stack
        int capacity = 10;                // Capacity of array

};

stack::stack()
{
    int *val = new int[capacity];
    buffer = val;
    top = 0;
}

bool stack::empty()
{
    if(top == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void stack::push(int x)
{
    if(top == capacity)
    {
        int *newArray = new int[capacity * 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = buffer[i];
            //cout << "newArray[" << i << "]: " << newArray[i] << endl;
        }
        buffer = newArray;
        delete[] newArray;
        newArray = NULL;
    }
    buffer[top] = x;
    top++;
}

void stack::pop()
{
    if(!empty())
    {
        top--;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack is empty!" << endl;
}

int& stack::topElem()
{
    return buffer[top - 1];
}

int main()
{
    stack plates;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  // Add 20 elements to the stack
    {
        plates.push(i);
    }

    while (!plates.empty())
    {
        cout << plates.topElem() << endl;      // Prints the elemtents of the stack
        plates.pop();                          // Pops the last element of the stack
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// Output
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
393
-1250224288
393
-1250206816

Comment: Delete NewArray is wrong - you want buffer there, and delete it before assigning NewArray to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer = newArray;
delete[] newArray;
```

this doesn't do what you expect. It points `buffer` to the new array, leaking the old one, then deleting the memory the buffer is pointing to.

You probably want something like:

```
delete[] buffer; // free the old buffer
buffer = newArray; // point it to the newly allocated memory
```